# How to add mult space text in a cell of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a table and want to add a multi space text to it.
Ex: HELLO<1stSPACE><2ndSPACE>WORLD. If i add as HELLO  WORLD, then its printing with single space.

Any help?

```
<th width="6%" class="textLeft width100px borderTopNone" style="vertical-align:top;font-size:14px; white-space: nowrap;" colspan="2">HELLO  WORLD</th>
```

Thanks

Comment: use a non-breaking space character instead of a `" "`. try `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 3):

add style

```
white-space: pre
```

for the containing element

Answer (score 1):

Before your text use `<pre>` tag. `<pre>` tag renders text in the format you type. But simple html tags removes extra spaces. Or even simpler, use `&nbsp` instead of your spaces.

```
<th width="6%" class="textLeft width100px borderTopNone" style="vertical-align:top;font-size:14px; white-space: nowrap;" colspan="2">
    HELLO&nbsp&nbspWORLD
</th>
```

Or :

```
<th width="6%" class="textLeft width100px borderTopNone" style="vertical-align:top;font-size:14px; white-space: nowrap;" colspan="2">
    <pre>HELLO  WORLD</pre>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&nbsp;` character entity as non breaking space - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dcq8gaLa/1/)**

`&nbsp;` - A common character entity used in HTML is the non breaking space.

**HTML:**

```
<th width="6%" class="textLeft width100px borderTopNone" style="vertical-align:top;font-size:14px; white-space: nowrap;" colspan="2">HELLO&nbsp;&nbsp;WORLD</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `word-spacing` CSS property, for example:

```
word-spacing: 1em;
```

Read more here:

- [word-spacing - CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-spacing/)
- [word-spacing - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing)

Here's [an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/tf4yuctq/) - the second table cell has extra spacing.

You can also use `white-space: pre` as suggested by others but it might not work in older IEs. And I can see you already set `white-space` to `nowrap`.

Or you can use `&nbsp;` to hard-code the space but it's usually better to use CSS.